# Troubleshoot - DVDrental PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've been going round and round on this and I can't figure out why this is failing.

Below is my PostgreSQL code and resulting error message, any help would be very appreciated. Everything appears to run and execute just fine until I try to call on my function RefreshReportData and then everything craps out. I'm basically trying to teach myself this so please be gentle with your criticism.

```
-- Detailed Table to hold report data
CREATE TABLE detailed_report (
    rental_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    rental_date TIMESTAMP,
    return_date TIMESTAMP,
    customer_id INT,
    film_title VARCHAR(255),
    rental_duration INT,
    rental_rate DECIMAL(5, 2),
    replacement_cost DECIMAL(8, 2),
    payment_amount DECIMAL(8, 2)
);

-- Summary Table to hold report data
CREATE TABLE summary_report (
    film_category VARCHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY,
    total_rentals INT,
    total_revenue DECIMAL(10, 2)
);

-- Extracting raw data for the detailed section of the report
SELECT
    r.rental_id,
    r.rental_date,
    r.return_date,
    r.customer_id,
    f.title AS film_title,
    f.rental_duration,
    f.rental_rate,
    f.replacement_cost,
    p.amount AS payment_amount
FROM
    rental r
JOIN
    inventory i ON r.inventory_id = i.inventory_id
JOIN
    film f ON i.film_id = f.film_id
JOIN
    payment p ON r.rental_id = p.rental_id;

-- Create a trigger to update the summary table when new rentals are added to the detailed table
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_summary_table_function() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    -- Increment total_rentals for the relevant film category
    UPDATE summary_report
    SET total_rentals = total_rentals + 1
    WHERE film_category = (SELECT category_id FROM film_category WHERE film_id = NEW.film_id);
    
    -- Update total_revenue based on the new rental's payment amount
    UPDATE summary_report
    SET total_revenue = total_revenue + NEW.payment_amount
    WHERE film_category = (SELECT category_id FROM film_category WHERE film_id = NEW.film_id);
    
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

-- Create the trigger
CREATE TRIGGER update_summary_table
AFTER INSERT ON detailed_report
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE FUNCTION update_summary_table_function();

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION RefreshReportData() RETURNS VOID AS $$
BEGIN
    -- Clear contents of detailed and summary tables
    DELETE FROM detailed_report;
    DELETE FROM summary_report;
    
    -- Insert fresh data into detailed_report (use the SQL query from part D)
    INSERT INTO detailed_report
    SELECT
        r.rental_id,
        r.rental_date,
        r.return_date,
        r.customer_id,
        f.title AS film_title,
        f.rental_duration,
        f.rental_rate,
        f.replacement_cost,
        p.amount AS payment_amount
    FROM
        rental r
    JOIN
        inventory i ON r.inventory_id = i.inventory_id
    JOIN
        film f ON i.film_id = f.film_id
    JOIN
        payment p ON r.rental_id = p.rental_id;
    
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

-- Custom transformation function to convert rental duration from days to hours
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ConvertDaysToHours(days INT) RETURNS INT AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN days * 24; -- Assuming 1 day = 24 hours
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

**I am getting the following Errors:
**

```
ERROR:  Key (rental_id)=(4591) already exists.duplicate key value violates unique constraint "detailed_report_pkey" 

ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "detailed_report_pkey"
SQL state: 23505
Detail: Key (rental_id)=(4591) already exists.
Context: SQL statement "INSERT INTO detailed_report
    SELECT
        r.rental_id,
        r.rental_date,
        r.return_date,
        r.customer_id,
        f.title AS film_title,
        f.rental_duration,
        f.rental_rate,
        f.replacement_cost,
        p.amount AS payment_amount
    FROM
        rental r
    JOIN
        inventory i ON r.inventory_id = i.inventory_id
    JOIN
        film f ON i.film_id = f.film_id
    JOIN
        payment p ON r.rental_id = p.rental_id"
PL/pgSQL function refreshreportdata() line 8 at SQL statement
```

Comment: Please get in the habit of reading errors and making an attempt to understand them. It doesn't look like you read the error based on your question. Your function tries to insert more than one record into the `detailed_report` that has the same primary key, and primary keys have to be unique, you can't have two rows in the `detailed_report` table with the same PK. So you likely have multiple entries in the`rental` or `payment` table that point to the same rental id. You might not wan `rental_id` to be a primary key on that table if that's an expected duplication.

Comment: well the error message is super clear. Probably somewhere in your join you are producing duplicates (on rental_id) that violates the primary key in detailed_report table

Comment: Also (IMO) FUNCTION ConvertDaysToHours is an overkill.  days*24 looks better

Comment: Using your test system create a new table without constraints and point your code at that. Run the report and then check where there are duplicates of what should be the PĶ!

Comment: People still rent DVD's?

Answer (score 0):

In the detailed_report table make sure that there is no duplicate value of rental_id, use this query to identify any duplicates;

```
SELECT rental_id, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM detailed_report
GROUP BY rental_id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

make sure that you are not calling RefreshReportData multiple times, also try implementing dta cleanup or conflict resolution if needed.

Hope it works :)

Comment: Wont give anything - the whole point is that the OP **can't** insert dupes!